# Verbose shutdown messages

Tags: freebsd

I am using BSD at the moment and think I have an X compatibility problem where my computer doesn't shut down. It can cause problems because I have to turn off the power manually while there is no display (so I don't know what stage the system shutdown is at.)

Does anyone know how to enable messages after log out, shutdown?

Comment: Have you taken a look in your log files like Xorg.log & syslog ?

Comment: Try to shutdown X first, then shutdown from tty console.
The timing of the error is significant, sometimes shutdown errors occur after filesystems are unmounted or after daemons are stopped, like syslogd.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answers.
I was asking is there a way to get the display to show the shutdown process as it is shutting down. Verbose boot is possible but I can't get display after X.
Tried CTRL+T.

Comment: Have you tried ctrl+alt+backspace to kill X?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a second device handy, turn on sshd and connect to the machine.  You might be able to look at the /var/log/messages plus the X logs after trying to shutdown X.  It might give you a clue as to what happened.  You can also try a shutdown this way instead of starting it from X.

I've had cases where my desktop screen froze up on FreeBSD in the past, and I was able to ssh in and shut it down cleanly.  Most of those cases involved compatibility issues with acceleration and disabling DRI/DRM solved it for me.  You could also see if it occurs with the VESA driver.

Comment: Thanks, Luke. I will try that if I can work out how to do it. I think my problem comes from logging out of Gnome, Openbox. KDE works ok.   Because of problems with X, I want to try and get rid of it completely so I can have a more simple setup (and shutdown messages displayed as they occur!).

Answer (score 1):

You can see the recent kernel messages in dmesg, maybe it'll be useful (some process can't be killed, or something similar). You can also check the old logs here:  /var/log/dmesg
Also, if you say there is no display, try to change your console to different: Ctrl-Alt-F1 to F8 and try to run dmesg there.